# Memory-efficient row-wise shuffle Polars

Tags: python-polars

A simple row-wise shuffle in Polars with

```
df = df.sample(frac=1.0)
```

has a peak memory usage of 2x the size of the dataframe (profiling with mprof).

Is there any fast way to perform a row-wise shuffle in Polars while keeping the memory usage down as much as possible? Shuffling column by column (or a batch of columns at a time) with the same seed (or `.take` with random index) does the trick but is quite slow.

Answer (score 3):

A shuffle is not `in-place`. Polars memory is often shared between columns/series/arrow.

A shuffle therefore has to allocate a new memory buffer. If we shuffle the whole `DataFrame` in parallel (which `sample` does). We allocate new buffers in parallel and write the shuffled data, hence the 2x memory usage.